# Delphi 2010 AsyncPro Fax

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fax

Don't get me started on why we have to use faxes but we have to. :(

Here's the issue.  We are using the AsyncPro fax controls in Delphi 2010 to send faxes. It all works well, EXCEPT, if we add an area code on to the recipients phone number, say 033539901 (with 1, for the dialing prefix) the fax machine rings, it answers, but refuses to accept the fax.
if I strip out the 03 (still using the 1, for the dialing prefix) it works fine !

We need the ability to send faxes to numbers outside the local calling area.

Has anyone see this issue before or have any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem. It sounds like a limitation of your office PBX.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your phone number is missing a digit in the area code segment.  If you live in a country where area codes are only 2 digits perhaps you are running into a code bias for North American area code conventions.